# Can this lamp socket handle a splitter/adapter that takes multiple light bulbs?

Tags: light, socket, lamp

I'd like to add two [socket adapters](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-660-Watt-Keyless-Twin-Socket-Lamp-Holder-Adapter-R52-00128-00W/100356967) to this lamp in order to put 4 bulbs in it to get more light. However, I'm confused by the message saying MAX 60 W Type A OR 10 W LED OR lamp adapter. Will this socket not be able to handle a socket splitter? The current LED bulbs I have (GE Relax 800 lumens) get pretty hot in the base.
[image: socket showing MAX 60 Watt Type A or 10 Watt LED].

Comment: Type A means the shape of the bulb, I believe. So this relates to the mechanics of that unit. The 60 W designation would suggest to me that the wiring is not rated for more than 1 A total. So long as you can keep your *four* bulbs under 1 A total and arrange things so that the bulbs can dissipate satisfactorily, I think you could be okay with four instead of just two. That should be doable with (4) 10 W LED bulbs.

Comment: The linked adapters might not be able to rotate in fully because of touching the lamp structure. Or the final position of the adapters may prevent attaching a bulb because the lamp is in the way.   Another possibility: Use larger wattage/lumens LED bulbs and use only the two bulbs without the adapters. As long as you stay at a 60 watt load or less load on each socket the lamp should support the loads.  Note that the socket also has a 10W LED light limit, which is probably related to heat control for the LED driver. Be sure the lamp's air flow is free not restricted.